# Set implementation that keeps insertion order and provides index access

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm currently searching for a Java implementation of a Set that keeps the original insertion order and provides access by index. Additionally I would like to have a bulk appendAll() method that takes another collection and appends it to the end (excpet for duplicates, sincethis is a Set).

[LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) goes somewhat in the right direction but it's missing index access and bulk append.

I could write this on my own, but why reinvent the whell?

Comment: What's wrong with [`addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))?

Comment: Given that a `Set` does not have a `get(index)` method in its interface, I dont see how this can be achieved. How do you plan to retrieve elements by index when the interface does not expose this operation ?

Comment: @DeepakBala He could create a class `MySet` that does have this operation and use that. You can add methods beyond those defined in `Set`.

Comment: It seems that you actually need an ArrayList which does not accept duplicates. Wouldn't be easier to subclass ArrayList?

Comment: @arshajii While that is true you can never return this Set to a caller and expect them to use this indexing feature. The caller will always need to know the underlying impl. I agree that the feature can be added, but it will come at the expense of polymorphism if the impl should necessarily be a `Set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [ListOrderedSet](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/set/ListOrderedSet.html) in Apache Commons?

> Decorates another Set to ensure that the **order of addition is retained and used by the iterator.**
>
> **If an object is added to the set for a second time, it will remain in the original position in the iteration.** The order can be observed from the set via the iterator or toArray methods.
>
> The ListOrderedSet also has various useful direct methods. These include many from List, such as **get(int)**, remove(int) and indexOf(int). An unmodifiable List view of the set can be obtained via asList().

It implements java.util.Set, though since `.get(index)` is not a method defined by Set, you'd need to make sure to pass it around as ListOrderedSet, not Set.